# Select the absence of HTML tag/element in CSS

Tags: html, css

I know that can sound strange, but sometimes I could need to detect an "empty line" using CSS only.

By "empty line", I mean a gap in the flow of HTML elements, an absence of element, and not an element with an empty content.

Here is a snippet to make it easier to understand:

```css
p {
  font-family: Calibri;
}

*:empty::after {
  content: '---';
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
<p>I know how to style the below "empty element"</p>
<p></p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>I'd like to style the below "no element / empty HTML line" ?</p>

<p>Text</p>
```

I know how to stylize empty elements.

Is there any way to stylize the absence of element?
I didn't find anything useful for the moment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you're trying to select an element without content?

Comment: Is using javascript and option?

Comment: @JacobSchneider Yes, or I could have maybe said a gap in the HTML flow. I don't know what will be the clearer.

Comment: I reckon for simplicity's sake, just say "empty tags".

Comment: That's not "empty tags", that's just "no tag at all".

Comment: CSS styles elements. You can't style any loose snippets of text, let alone just white space with CSS.

Comment: If you have multiple blank lines, do you want all of them to have the `---` added to it?

Comment: @Danny there is only *one* downvote so We cannot really talk about downvoted. Maybe someone miss clicked or simply don't like the question or don't find the question useful. I don't think commenting to say *why there is a downvote* is really something useful, it's a part of the site so no need to be surprised.

Comment: @TakitIsy and what is the purpose of doing this? as you can see the html render without this empty line. so technically there is no difference between having one, many or no line

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree that seems akward. But sometimes that empty line means something and we could want to stylize it or what is right after. Nice to see you in your disguise, anyway !

Comment: but can you share a real case whree we can see that empty line because in your code it's actually not visible .. probably if you give more context you will get better answers

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can get the functionality you want with pure CSS but you could use javascript to check when a `p` elements next sibling includes more than 1 newline character and if so add a class to it.

See the demo below:

```js
let allPElements = document.querySelectorAll("p");

for( let p of allPElements) {
  if(p.nextSibling.textContent.includes("\n\n")) {
    p.classList.add("empty");
  }
}
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Calibri;
}

.empty::after, *:empty::after {
  display:  table; /* Make sure element is a new line*/
  content: '---';
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
<p>I know how to style the below "empty element"</p>
<p></p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>I'd like to style the below "no element / empty HTML line" ?</p>

<p>Text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not entirely convinced that this is the best solution, this does provide a possible way around your problem. You can grab all the content/html which you want to apply the "blank" line rule to and then use `.split(/\n/)` to get an array of all the lines. Then, you can replace all the blank lines within you array with an empty element so your css style will apply to it.

See working example below:

```js
let lines = $('.content').html().split(/\n/).slice(1, -1);
let newHTML = lines.reduce((acc, elem, i) => acc+(elem == "" ? "<span></span>" : elem) + '\n', '');

$('.content').html(newHTML);
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Calibri;
}

:empty::after {
  content: '---';
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<div class="content">
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>I know how to style the below "empty element"</p>
  <p></p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>I'd like to style the below "no element / empty HTML line" ?</p>

  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using the `:empty` pseudoclass seems to work for me, here's a pen that demonstrates it

https://codepen.io/klaussmc/pen/XoXQpG

although selecting the element following an empty one is a much more difficult taks, I would use JS in this case.

[Here's](https://codepen.io/klaussmc/pen/XoXQpG?editors=1111) a working demo showing how you can achieve this in JS

Comment: I know how to use `:empty`, notice that I did it in my snippet. That's not what I asked.